# multiple ajax and form post requests on multiple pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I am making a small social website just for practice where for example user can open `chat box` on any page (`/profile` or `/home`). And there are more than one ajax post requests per page like `sendmessage` form can post to `/home` and `sharepost` can also post to `/home`. Moreover, `sendmessage` and `sharepost` requests can also be submitted on any other site page. 
I am using `Laravel 5.1` so please advise me accordingly that how I should handle this problem.
Currently, I am doing this using `Laravel Jobs`.

```
public function homePostsRequests(Request $request){
        if ($request->has('submitPost')) {
            return $this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\StorePost($request));
        } else if ($request->has('sendMessage')) {
            return $this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\StoreMessage($request));
        }
        return 'no action found';
    }
```

But in case of ajax request, submit button is not set i think that's why it is not working for `ajax requests`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is submitted normally all the form element values are submitted to the target endpoint. In case of the Ajax requests it's you that should post the required values manually. If you are using jQuery for sending the request you should add a key, value pair to the `data` property for `submitPost`.